# How to create bullet impact effects?

Tags: first-person-shooter

I'm creating a small fps and I don't know how to create a bullet impact effect. I have a muzzle flare and I have recasting set up but I don't know how to make a bullet impact effect. I've already tried working with the particle system prefab 'Flare' but nothing seems to work for me, please can someone help?  **Soon Please**

Comment: What's the appearance you want to create? How have you tried to create it so far? What went wrong with those attempts? Is it safe to guess that you're working in Unity (since you didn't tag your question with any information about your tools / tech stack)?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for a combination of the following concepts:

1. **Particle system** for the bullet hitting a surface (i.e. sparks on hitting metal, wood splints on hitting wood etc.)
2. **Decals** to allow projectiles to leave hit marks